# How can I pass data to a protobuf `oneof` in tonic?

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers, grpc, prost

How can I pass data to a protobuf `oneof` in [tonic](https://github.com/hyperium/tonic)?

I couldn't find any instruction or example in the docs.

Answer (score 6):

Tonic should generate an `enum` and corresponding type for each `oneof` variant. You'll have to match on that.

---

I'm assuming `tonic = "0.4.3"` and `prost = "0.7.0"` or higher for this answer. Let's use the following `.proto` definition as an example:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package stack_overflow;

service StackOverflow {
  rpc Question (HelpRequest) returns (HelpResponse);
}

message HelpRequest {
  oneof foo {
    FroozleType froozle = 1;
    FrobnikType frobnik = 2;
  }
}

message FroozleType {
  int32 value = 1;
}
message FrobnikType {}

message HelpResponse {
  oneof bar {
    QuxType qux = 1;
    BazType baz = 2;
  }
}

message QuxType {
  int32 answer = 1;
}
message BazType {
  string comment = 1;
}
```

When built, this generates the following types and traits. For the service:

- `stack_overflow_server::StackOverflow`: the server trait

For the requests:

- `HelpRequest`: the struct for the request message
- `help_request::Foo`: an enum for the `oneof foo` in the request having an `Froozle` and a `Frobnik` variant
- `FroozleType`: the struct of the `FroozleType` message
- `FrobnikType`: the struct of the `FrobnikType` message

For the replies:

- `HelpResponse`: the struct for the response message
- `help_response::Bar`: an enum for the `oneof bar` in the response having an `Qux` and a `Baz` variant
- `QuxType`: the struct of the `QuxType` message
- `BazType`: the struct of the `BazType` message

For example, the `HelpRequest` struct and `help_request::Foo` enum are defined as such:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, ::prost::Message)]
pub struct HelpRequest {
    #[prost(oneof = "help_request::Foo", tags = "1, 2")]
    pub foo: ::core::option::Option<help_request::Foo>,
}

/// Nested message and enum types in `HelpRequest`.
pub mod help_request {
    #[derive(Clone, PartialEq, ::prost::Oneof)]
    pub enum Foo {
        #[prost(message, tag = "1")]
        Froozle(super::FroozleType),
        #[prost(message, tag = "2")]
        Frobnik(super::FrobnikType),
    }
}
```

Sticking it all together, an example implementation of the above service could look like this:

```rust
use tonic::{Request, Response, Status};

mod grpc {
    tonic::include_proto!("stack_overflow");
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct StackOverflowService {}

#[tonic::async_trait]
impl grpc::stack_overflow_server::StackOverflow for StackOverflowService {
    async fn question(
        &self,
        request: Request<grpc::HelpRequest>,
    ) -> Result<Response<grpc::HelpResponse>, Status> {
        let request = request.into_inner();

        let bar = match request.foo {
            Some(grpc::help_request::Foo::Froozle(froozle)) => {
                Some(grpc::help_response::Bar::Qux(grpc::QuxType {
                    answer: froozle.value + 42,
                }))
            }
            Some(grpc::help_request::Foo::Frobnik(_)) => {
                Some(grpc::help_response::Bar::Baz(grpc::BazType {
                    comment: "forty-two".into(),
                }))
            }
            None => None,
        };

        let reply = grpc::HelpResponse { bar };
        return Ok(Response::new(reply));
    }
}
```